# Last Row in a column in excel file using C# (cells does not have get_end method)

Tags: c#, excel

When I try and call Cells[fullRow, 1].get_end I get an error, object does not contain a definition for get_end and no extension method could be found.

I never saw anyone complain about this or describe this in comments of old stack overflow threads re the subject of finding last row in an excel column using C#

```
string path = @"Z:\New folder\Test123.xlsx";
    MyApp = new Excel.Application();
    MyApp.Visible = true;
    MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
    MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[1];

    int fullRow = MySheet.Rows.Count;
    int LastRow = MySheet.Cells[1,1].get_end(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
```

Comment: Where you were about to go up from `A1` cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign the return from `MySheet.Cells[1, 1]` in to a Range object or call the function `End`, you should find that it works as expected.
Also, note the case of the function, it is meant to be: `get_End`.

```
        // Working
        Excel.Range firstCell1 = MySheet.Cells[1, 1];
        int LastRow1 = firstCell1.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;

        // Working
        Excel.Range firstCell2 = MySheet.Cells[fullRow, 1];
        int LastRow2 = firstCell2.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;

        // Working
        int LastRow3 = MySheet.Cells[fullRow, 1].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;

        // Does not work
        int LastRow4 = MySheet.Cells[1, 1].get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
```

I believe the problem is down to the Dynamic Binding done at runtime for COM Interop, but, I am not 100% certain of the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
void Main()
{

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wkb;
    app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    wkb = app.Workbooks.Open(@"e:\temp\test.xlsx");
    int row = GetLastRow(wkb, "sheet1", "A");
    Console.WriteLine(row);
    app.Quit();
}

int GetLastRow(Workbook wkb, string sheet, string column)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sht = wkb.Worksheets[sheet] as Worksheet;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = sht.Range[column + ":" + column];
    range = range.Cells[range.Rows.Count, range.Column] as Range;
    return range.End[XlDirection.xlUp].Row;
}
```

You can remove all that Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel stuff adding the appropriate using directive.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem. Did you try?

Comment: Changed example to pass a workbook to the GetLastRow method, of course you can change the method signature at the same way to pass the worksheet. Or leave it as is and call it by name.